# How to Merge 2 Google Sheets tables on Date?

Tags: date, google-sheets, merge, datatables

I would like to merge 2 Google Sheets tables by **Date**... but would like **Profit** to recalculate as well. These are the only 2 columns I am concerned with but if you want to perform the same function to each of the other columns that is great too.

Note that not every day bets are made by both Teams and Props. The **Profit** I am looking for is a running total of both Teams and Props combined. There were no Prop bets made on 4/15 in this example.

Here is my 1st table (TEAMS):

[image: TEAMS TABLE]

Here is my 2nd table (PROPS):

[image: PROPS Table]

Here is a recap of the days:

TEAMS

```
Date    Profit
4/15    14,292
4/14    13,452
4/13    13,692
4/12    14,922
```

PROPS

```
Date    Profit
4/14    16,896
4/13    17,364
4/12    17,604
```

Here is the output that I am looking for which is a summation of the running Profit total from the combined Teams and Props. Note that the last day no Prop bets have been made yet... so the running total should use the PROP profit from the day prior.

For example, the summation for the last day would be the total TEAM profit for 4/15 (14,292) plus the total PROP profit from the day before on 4/14 (16,896)... so 14,292 + 16,896 = 31,188.

[image: Combined Table]

IF the combined total Profit complicates everything I can likely create a new formula for that column.

Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer... and feel free to ask questions so that I can clarify anything that is unclear.

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet so that we can work on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generalized scenario of how to work it out. Adjust the ranges in the formula as per your sheet design.

```
=let(Σ,A3:A,
     Δ,E3:E,
     Γ,index(if(len(Σ),xlookup(Σ,G:G,K:K,0),)),
     Ξ,index(if(len(Σ),Δ+xlookup(Σ,G:G,K:K,,-1),)),
       {Σ,Δ,Γ,Ξ})
```

[image]

Comment: Ty @rockinfreakshow for this response! I was not aware google sheets used those additional symbols (Σ,Δ,Γ,Ξ). I will have time to look at this today. Ty sir! =)

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly!!! I would have never figured this out myself. Thank you so much sir for taking the time to answer this. I will learn a lot from it.